# Unable to resolve Serlog.Exceptions reference in build pipeline

Tags: c#, .net-4.7

My .NET Framework 4.7 App will not build in my CI pipeline, thought it will build in Visual Studio 2022

I get the following messages in the build logs

```
Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Serilog.Exceptions...Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
...
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Exceptions' does not exist in the namespace 'Serilog' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade to a newer version of Nuget** (3.4.4 -> 6.5.0)

The package was being installed in `packages\Serilog.Exceptions.8.4.0+build.694` instead of `packages\Serilog.Exceptions.8.4.0` by Nuget 3.4.4:

```
Restoring NuGet package Serilog.Exceptions.8.4.0.
...
Installing Serilog.Exceptions 8.4.0.
...
Adding package 'Serilog.Exceptions.8.4.0+build.694' to folder 'D:\a\1\s\packages'
```